# Animate WPF Text when binding updates, how?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, animation, effects

I want to be able to create a fade animation on a text element when the
binding to that element updates. In other words, the effect is that as
text gets added to a text box one sees a fading effect as the text updates
and then fades out. I do'nt know how to achieve this. I have seen something similar
using an `EventTrigger` on a `RoutedEvent` such as `FrameworkElement.Loaded` but how does one detect when a binding updates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can set properties on your binding that will cause events to be fired. There are two properties available:

1. **NotifyOnSourceUpdated**: Raise the *SourceUpdated* event when a value is transferred from the binding target to the binding source.
2. **NotifyOnTargetUpdated**: Raise the *TargetUpdated* event when a value is transferred from the binding source to the binding target.

From the description of your setup, it sounds like you want to use *NotifyOnTargetUpdated*. Set that to true in your binding, then whenever the target updates, the [Binding.TargetUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.targetupdated.aspx) event will fire. You can then listen to that event in an EventTrigger, and fade your text.

Comment: Unfortunately, FrameworkElement.TargetUpdated is not a RoutedEvent and, therefore, cannot be used in an EventTrigger.

Comment: Ah- I was very close. You have to use the attached event (Binding.TargetUpdated).