# Animate Image when loaded in Image Control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, animation

I want to create a slideshow of images. For this I have loaded new images in image control after every set interval of time. But each time i load a new image it comes without any animation I need to load each image with a transition animation or fade in-out animation. How can I achieve animation while changing images in Image control? Following is the code:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
<Image Source="{Binding CurrentImage}" />
</Grid>
```

**XAML.cs**

```
ViewModel = new ScreenSaverViewModel();
this.DataContext = ViewModel;
```

ViewModel.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the current image to display on the attract screen. Changes to this property 
/// cause the PropertyChanged event to be signaled
/// </summary>
public string CurrentImage
{
    get { return this.currentImage; }
    protected set
    {
        this.currentImage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentImage");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the observable collection of all images.
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<string> Images
{
    get { return this.images; }
}

public ScreenSaverViewModel()
{
    images = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    this.LoadSlideShowImages();

    if (Images != null && Images.Count > 0)
    {
        this.CurrentImage = this.Images[this.currentIndex];

        this.tickTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        this.tickTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TimerIntervalMilliseconds);
        this.tickTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.currentIndex++;
            this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex < this.Images.Count ? this.currentIndex : 0;
            this.CurrentImage = this.Images[this.currentIndex];
        };

        // start the timer after image is loaded
        this.tickTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use story board http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073573/how-do-i-create-a-rotate-animation-on-an-image-object-using-c-sharp-code-only-i

Comment: But how would i animate on change of new image? means it should look like new image is loaded with animation.

Comment: You could have two overlaying images. Fade in top image, set bottom image, fade out top image, set top image, repeat.
Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165862/animate-wpf-text-when-binding-updates-how) might be of help.

Comment: Can't I create some trigger that fires when Image source changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a class inheriting Image control in which I have raised property change when Source of image control changes. on which I have applied trigger this works fine now. Following is the code:

```
<controls:ImageControl   Source="{Binding CurrentImage}" >
            <controls:ImageControl.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="controls:ImageControl.SourceChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Opacity)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </controls:ImageControl.Triggers>
        </controls:ImageControl>


  public class ImageControl : Image
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent SourceChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
      "SourceChanged", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ImageControl));

        static ImageControl()
        {
            Image.SourceProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SourcePropertyChanged));
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler SourceChanged
        {
            add { AddHandler(SourceChangedEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(SourceChangedEvent, value); }
        }

        private static void SourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image image = obj as Image;
            if (image != null)
            {
                image.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(SourceChangedEvent));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

Please run this code separately.

```
<Grid Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard >
                <Storyboard  >
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:06"  RepeatBehavior="Forever"  Storyboard.TargetName="img1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="image1.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="image2.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="image3.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="img1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.1" To="1" Duration="00:00:02"></DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Image x:Name="img1" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
</Grid>
```

**Update**

```
 <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop" x:Key="FadeOut">
        <DoubleAnimation FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetName="ScreensaverImage" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0.05" To="1" Duration="0:0:2">
        </DoubleAnimation>
  </Storyboard>

 <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop" x:Key="FadeIn">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ScreensaverImage" FillBehavior="Stop" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"  From="1" To=".05" Duration="0:0:2">
        </DoubleAnimation>
  </Storyboard>

<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="ScreensaverImage"></Image>
</Grid>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    List<Uri> savedImage = new List<Uri>();
    int i = 0;
    Storyboard fadeIn, fadeOut;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        savedImage.Add(new Uri("image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
        savedImage.Add(new Uri("image2.png", UriKind.Relative));
        savedImage.Add(new Uri("image3.png", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (savedImage.Count > 0)
        {
            fadeIn = (Storyboard)this.Resources["FadeIn"];
            fadeOut = (Storyboard)this.Resources["FadeOut"];

            fadeIn.Completed += fadeIn_Completed;
            fadeOut.Completed += fadeOut_Completed;
            ScreensaverImage.Source = new BitmapImage(savedImage[i++]);
            if (savedImage.Count > 1)
            {
                BeginStoryboard(fadeOut);

            }
            ScreensaverImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            ScreensaverImage.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    void fadeOut_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fadeIn.Begin();
    }

    void fadeIn_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (i == savedImage.Count)
            i = 0;
        ScreensaverImage.Source = new BitmapImage(savedImage[i++]);
        fadeOut.Begin();
    }



}
```

Comment: This would have worked if the number of images were constant... I have load the images from a directory first and then load one at a time after certain time interval. So can you tell me how would i change the code accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

you can use the MetroImageControl or MetroContentControl that provided in:
    [Mahapps library for metro style](http://mahapps.com/)